# Where to find source code for numpy's percentile

Tags: python, numpy

Where can I find the source code behind the `percentile` function in `numpy`? I want to inspect it. I have searched Google but haven't come up with anything yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To find it on your own system, try `inspect`:

```
import inspect
from numpy import percentile
inspect.getfile(percentile)
```

Comment: To print the source: `print(inspect.getsource(numpy.percentile))`

Answer (score 8):

The source code of `numpy` is in [Github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/) and the percentile function can be found on [line 3076 in lib/function_base.py](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3076)

Comment: For the record the percentile function is now on [line 3796](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3796) of lib/function_base.py in master.

Answer (score 5):

With `ipython` you can view the source code by putting `??` (two question marks) after the function,

```
from numpy import percentile

percentile??
```

Answer (score 3):

The `source` function in `numpy`

```
from numpy import percentile, source
print source(percentile)
```

will output the source code.